# Visual Studio SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2019

I have a question regarding Visual Studio 2019, I have a few projects that I created where the project folders were saved on a shared drive on a specific server. They have since decommissioned the server and the shared drive as well and I now don't have any of these Project Folders. All my reports are still running like clockwork though with updated data. Can anyone perhaps explain to me why that is?

Comment: The reports you see in VS are the rdl files that you develop. At some point you  will deploy them to the server. It's the reports on the SSRS server that are running OK I assume?

If you need to get the reports back to work on, you can download the rdl direct from the web portal.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, I will do some more research on downloading from the web portal and hopefully I can rescue all the reports I lost on that server.

Comment: No problem. You can right-click the report tile in the web portal and just choose "Download". There are ways to download everything in one go such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065377